# select com limit no firebird

Tags: sql, firebird

Eu faço no mysql para buscar os 1000 ultimos regitros:

```
select * from tabela order by id desc limit 1000;
```

Agora, como se faz isso no Firebird?

fazendo desse jeito tenho a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> *Dynamic SQL Error
>   -SQL error code = @1
>   -Token unknown - line @1, column @2
>   -@1*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT FIRST 1000 * FROM tabela ORDER BY id DESC;
```

`LIMIT` é uma clausula exclusiva de PostgreSQL e MySQL.